# Local share access problem

Tags: networking, router

since my last boot I've been having a weird issue: I can easily access the internet, and ping various websites, however I can't ping any address on my local network. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with Gnome 3 desktop.

this is my routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

I have no idea if the metric is wrong but I wouldn't know how to change that anyway.
Does anyone have a solution? What more information do you need me to post to figure out the issue?

Thanks for the help

Comment: We'd need the actual ping command. Are you pinging IPs or names? You should also show the command that printed that routing table just so we know for sure what we're seeing.

Comment: Can you provide output from `sudo arp-scan 192.168.1.0/24`. `arp-scan` you can install with command `sudo apt-get install arp-scan`

Comment: @terdon the ping command i used is `ping 192.168.1.10` the address refers to another network pc; the command I used for the routing table is simply `route`

Comment: @2707974 the result is:
`ioctl: Cannot assign requested address
WARNING: Could not obtain IP address for interface eth0. Using 0.0.0.0 for
the source address, which is probably not what you want.
Either configure eth0 with an IP address, or manually specify the address
with the --arpspa option.
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)

0 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 1.812 seconds (141.28 hosts/sec). 0 responded`

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete manual `sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 192.168.1.0/24` This will put arp scan via wlan0, your wless connection, to localnet. Any host on network 192.168.1.0/24 probably will respond. When you got arp table with host mac and ip address you can try to ping them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so after trying with ethernet port and after the help from 2707974 I managed to solve the problem. apparently metric 0 was the problem, the ethernet interface worked allright and the metric value was 1, so i changed the metric value of the wlan interface and everything got back to normal, to change that I used:

```
sudo ifmetric wlan0 1
```